# KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, pandas

I have condition with following using [].

```
 res['BB'] = np.where( 
                     np.logical_and(res['close'].shift(-2) > smapre2[res["close"].shift(-2).index],  
                     res['close'].shift(-2) > smapre[res["close"].shift(-2).index] 
                   ),1,0)
```

But I am getting this error in command line. However, it is working in Spyder(Python 3.8).

```
KeyError : "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. 
The following labels were missing: 
DatetimeIndex(['2020-11-01 21:00:00', '2020-11-01 21:20:00',\n
               '2020-11-01 21:40:00', '2020-11-01 22:00:00',\n 
              '2020-11-01 22:20:00',\n
               ...\n
               '2020-11-12 22:00:00', '2020-11-12 22:20:00',\n               
               '2020-11-12 22:40:00', '2020-11-12 23:00:00',\n
               '2020-11-12 23:20:00'],\n
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='timestamp', length=800, freq='20T'). 

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"
```

How can I fix the error in this.